# Got java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download plugin error using SonarQube in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan, socketexception

My process to use SonarQube:

1. I installed SonarQube in Azure App Service and start it by
   StartSonar.bat.
2. Add a new project and generate a token.
3. Add service connection in Azure Devops with the token.
4. Add SonarQube tasks in pipeline with process provide by https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-azure-devops/.

When I run this pipeline, I got java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download plugin error in SonarQubeAnalyze task, shown as following:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download plugin [kotlin] into C:\Users\VssAdministrator.sonar_tmp\fileCache6519814482966957451.tmp
>   at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.PluginFiles.downloadBinaryTo(PluginFiles.java:152)
>   at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.PluginFiles.download(PluginFiles.java:108)
>   at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.PluginFiles.get(PluginFiles.java:89)
>   at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.loadPlugins(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:77)
>   at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller.installRemotes(ScannerPluginInstaller.java:60)
>       at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginRepository.start(ScannerPluginRepository.java:59)
>       at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.start(StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.java:40)
>   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
>   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
>   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)

The log shows that error was caused by java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (sometimes Read Timeout)

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
>       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
>       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
>       at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)

I have no idea about how this error happens or how to solve it.

Hope someone could help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by turn on Web Sockets in Azure App Service Configuration.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, please consider [accepting your reply as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after the limitation of 48 hours and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have a sonar plugin added to your project. Also, add the sonar host url and token properties to the project and give it a try.

For maven :-

```
<sonar.host.url>sonar host url</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.login> token you generated on sonarqube server</sonar.login>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi Ambuj, is that possible to only config it in Azure Devops without make change in source code?

Comment: Not sure about that. But plugin must be added to code so that you can run the sonar:sonar goal for analyzing the source code. Once analysis is done, it generates the report jacoco.exec file which is uploaded to sonarqube server using the sonar properties(host and login details).  Sonarqube uses that report to show the all analyses on the dashboard.

Comment: As I tested, there is no need to add plugin in source code. Maybe the SonarQube extension in Azure Devops did it for me.